# how to call https post request in swift language?

Tags: ios, xcode, asynchronous, swift

I want to find a simple way to call `https` post request `asynchronously` in new iOS `Swift` language.

And how we will get the callbacks once the response is sent.

Comment: use something like Alamofire https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire. There's tutorials on how to use it there

Comment: Have a read of the `NSURLSession` docs.